# Presto JDBC Call statements

Tags: java, jdbc, presto, presto-jdbc

Is it possible to execute `CALL system.sync_partition_metadata('dummy','dummy','FULL')` using JDBC as Presto JDBC driver does not support CallableStatements?

Comment: Why not ask on their forum? Link available on their [Presto Community](https://prestodb.io/community.html) page.

Answer (score 4):

Presto JDBC driver does not support `io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoConnection#prepareCall` methods ([please file an issue](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/new)), but you can use `Statement` for this:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:presto://localhost:8080/hive/default", "presto", "")) {
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        boolean hasResultSet = statement.execute("CALL system.sync_partition_metadata('default', 'table_name', 'FULL')");
        verify(!hasResultSet, "unexpected resultSet");
    }
}
```

(BTW you can get always get more help with Presto on [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html))

Comment: Thank you Piotr. I have filed an issue for this.